# Multi kernel usage in Linux PC(UBUNTU)

Tags: linux-kernel

I have 2.6.32-21-generic , 2.6.32-38-generic and 3.0.0-20-generic.
My current kernel is:-

```
$ uname -r
2.6.32-38-generic
```

I want to use different kernel that is  2.6.32-21-generic.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

After the BIOS, press Esc repeatedly until you see a screen that lets you choose between kernels.

Comment: That I know. But can I do that I run my system in one kernel that is 2.6.32-38-generic but compile my driver using 2.6.32-21-generic kernel.?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Please be more specific.

Comment: Like at bootup I select kernel 3.0.0-20-generic.So my system will boot with same kernel.Now I have one test driver(module) which I want to compile for kernel 2.6.32-21-generic and run it. I want to do so because  2.6.32-21-generic is providing the functionality(which I am using in my driver) that 3.0.0-20-generic does not have in it.
Hope you got my point.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use a driver compiled for version X with kernel version Y. That is not possible.

Comment: thank you.
Now I want to put need kernel in my PC.How can I do that?

Comment: So you want to install a kernel you compiled? 'make modules_install && make install' as root in the kernel source directory. I don't know how Ubuntu deals with updating Grub, I don't use it, maybe you might need an extra step. Does someone else know?